# Impact of Topological data analysis on Monero

Tags: privacy, ring-signatures, stealth-address, blockchain-analysis, metadata

What is Topological data analysis? Can it be used to study the Monero blockchain and degrade the privacy of transactions as claimed by Gary Le in the interview referenced by [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/a/2725/185)?