# Which mining of Monero is more cost efficient CPU or GPU?

Tags: cpu-mining, gpu-mining, hashrate-comparison

Which mining of Monero is more cost efficient (both use same expensive energy) CPU ([INTEL CORE I3-6300T LOW POWER TRAY PROCESOR - CM8066201927004](http://ark.intel.com/products/90728/Intel-Core-i3-6300T-Processor-4M-Cache-3_30-GHz)) or GPU ([Nvidia 750Ti](http://www.nvidia.com/gtx-700-graphics-cards/gtx-750ti/))?

I know [GPU mining gives you higher hashrate](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/41/which-type-of-hardware-is-the-most-efficient-for-mining-monero) but it also uses more energy.

Comment: An answer to this would be speculative unless you define energy costs and the specific CPU and GPU you would like to see compared.

Comment: Yes, you are right. But about energy costs is same in both cases so is not important. Since soem say Nvidia 750Ti is one of most cost efficient GPU i will put comparison with one same worth CPU.

Comment: Usually GPU mining is more efficient, but since you use a Nvidia it may be even.

Comment: Although NVIDIA cards are generally worse at mining than AMD cards, the 750 Ti is the exception because of its relatively low cost and energy efficiency.

Answer (score 5):

The NVIDIA 750 Ti returns about 250 H/s with about 60W of energy ([hash source](http://cryptomining-blog.com/2953-updated-ccminer-fork-for-cryptonight-with-better-performance/), [wattage source](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/geforce-gtx-750-ti-review,3750-21.html)).

I do not have data on the i3-6300T, but the AMD FX 8350 also returns about 250 H/s ([source](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MI-ic0Os25hgGUImW54sUIjZY_pUNQNa_W8Se5pRGBs/edit?pli=1#gid=0)), and this should be a faster processor than the i3-6300T (I'm guessing 150 H/s). The i3-6300T uses about 30W ([source](http://ark.intel.com/products/90728/Intel-Core-i3-6300T-Processor-4M-Cache-3_30-GHz)).

Use the Monero mining calculator [here](http://www.coinwarz.com/calculators/monero-mining-calculator) to determine which is best for you based on your energy cost.

Answer (score 5):

According to [MoneroBenchmarks](https://monerobenchmarks.info/), the **i3-6300** does 150H/s at 65W and the Nvidia **750Ti** does around 250H/s at 60W. So, seems that at the same energy expense the GPU card can give you definitely more hash rate.

*Update:* **AMD Ryzen CPU** and **AMD RX 550/560 GPU** cards can mine Monero with high hashrate and low power consumption. Also **RX570/580** and **VEGA** cards have nice rate/power ratio. For building a cheap rig with a decent hashrate and really low power consumption, **AMD RX 550/560 GPU** cards are the most used solution.

Check [this answer](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/41/which-type-of-hardware-is-the-most-efficient-for-mining-monero/7075#7075) for more details about which type of hardware is the most efficient for mining **Monero**.

Answer (score 5):

The most efficient way to mine Monero now is using AMD Radeon Vega 56/64 cards.

Overclocking the HBM and undervolting the card while runing Cast's XMR miner gives about 2 KH/s for about 150W.

An i3 6100T will net you around 60-80 H/s on xmr-stak-cpu optimized by fireice with settings tweaked which is neglegible as most pools pay out at >0.5 XMR.