# how to calculated how much H/s can my GPU do for different types of cryptocurrencies?

Tags: mining-pools, gpu-mining, hashrate

How can I calculated how much H/s can my GPU do as a function of the type of gpu, the difficult of the cryptocurrency and time? 
You can calculate this with https://www.nicehash.com/?p=calc, https://www.cryptocompare.com/mining/#/equipment  but they miss many important cryptocurrencies.

Many Thanks

Comment: you can download the actual nicehash miner, and whatever crypto currencies  that it supports, you can run "Benchmark Algorithm" for each currency you want, also you could download the miner for each crypto currency you want and just point it at a pool and see what you end up getting for a hashrate

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to calculate. There's either data available based on what people are reporting, or there's not.

Mining performance is dependent on the mining algorithm used. Monero uses CryptoNight, and for that you can find a list here: [Which type of hardware is the most efficient for mining Monero?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/41/which-type-of-hardware-is-the-most-efficient-for-mining-monero) It should be the same for any cryptocurrency using CryptoNight.

For non-CryptoNight cryptocurrencies, I doubt you'll find an answer here as this StackExchange site is focused on Monero and other CryptoNote cryptocurrencies.

Comment: I also want to add a nice site I came across with monery benchmarks http://monerobenchmarks.info/